# How to add an exception to the "show desktop" functionnality?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, notes

I've been looking everywhere for this :
I want to add an exception so that when i use "show desktop", all windows are minimized EXCEPT the notes app.

Usually to show the desktop I use the "corner bar" Cinnamon applet (on linux mint), but I would also be interested in any solutions involving keyboard shortcuts or wmctrl (I guess I could write a little script to minimize all apps except this one, and replace "corner bar" with an applet that launches that script).

The old sticky notes Cinnamon applet used to work like that by default, but it is not compatible at all with the new version of Cinnamon, and I can't figure out how to configure that behavior for the new sticky notes app (which is a normal app, not an applet). I miss it!

I also tried a bunch of other notes apps hoping one of them had this feature and I did not find one. I seriously considered forking the old applet and trying to make it compatible with the new version of Cinnamon, but I think that is above my skills level.

Comment: "write a little script to minimize all apps except this one," <-- yup, do that.